# python code can't find file while its in folder marked as resource root in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

In PyCharm, I created folder named test, created txt file named test inside and marked folder as content root. When I added python file outside the test folder and tried to access test.txt file with open it suggested me file name. But when I tried running the code it couldn't find the file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elmo/PycharmProjects/TBC_PAY_API_TESTING/testing.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(open("test.txt").read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

This is how the code and folders look like ( ingore the trash folder)
[image]

How can I fix it? The main reason I am doing this is to avoid writing full path's for accessing file.

Comment: There are two different things. One is about relative module loading, and the other is about working directory.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi can you explain what do you mean by that

Comment: See the answer below (and remember to upvote, and accept, if the answer answers your question.

Comment: well, it didn't really help me cause in my case where there are too many folders nested into each other, the only solution would be to be able to access any file from anywhere. In this case writing full path is the only choice i guess.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you totally. All complex projects have many nested folders, it is not an unique phenomenon. I don't agree with you that you have only one choice to use the (hard-coded) full path in your case. If you check my answer, you can see three different solution to define your file's path. Furthermore the Python provides you many solution to define a path. If you check the Google, you can find many site which describes the file path dealing. Eg.: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f

Comment: @milanbalazs first two solutions you gave me of course i already knew about them, as for third one, when my goal is to write less code, writing additional 3 lines just to access file wont really help me

Comment: I just dont understand, if after making resource root folder, files inside can be detected from anywhere, why can't i use those files

Comment: Maybe you missed the `__FILE__` in the answer. In such manner, you have the location of the source file, so you can work from there to the relative location of the file.  "Root resource" tell just pycharm where to look modules, for error highlighting, it has no meaning on executing code. But if it is a test, you may want do set your working directory on correct path

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about two totally different things in your question. If you mark a folder as `Sources root` that means the Python interpreter will be able to find the modules in that folder.

**For example:**

When you write an own module and you want to use it in another file the Python won't find it automatically. The `PYTHONPATH` should contain the path of the folder which contains your module. And actually the `Sources root` option does this!

The other thing what you have mentioned in your question is that you don't provided a correct path in your code. It is a real error. In your code, you have to provide the correct path for `open`. The `Pycharm` is an IDE but your (or other's) Python interpreter will use your code.

You can solve your problem in many ways.

**For example:**

You can hard-code the path of your txt (It is totally not recommended):

```
print(open("/home/elmo/PycharmProjects/TBC_PAY_API_TESTING/test/text.txt").read())
```

You can use relative path:

```
print(open("test/text.txt").read())
```

You can use full path based on your Python file (I recommend this solution):

```
import os

dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  # Directory of your Python file
file_path = os.path.join(dir, "test", "test.txt")  # Create the path of the file
print(open(file_path).read())
```